# Xml Parse in Android:: using DOM

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing, using

I am new to android, I tried XML parse with SAX previously but I got Exception in Network,I tried lot with that , But not able to get that, many suggest to use AsyncTask, I tried with that , But again failed, So  I tried with DOM now, Again same got some exception in android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException and gralloc_goldfish error (i.e) Emulator without GPU emulation detected .... help me for this problem. i gng this program for 2 days

Program::XMLParsingDOMExample.java

```
package com.androidpeople.xml.parsing;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class XMLParsingDOMExample extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/** Create a new layout to display the view */
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(1);
/** Create a new textview array to display the results */
TextView name[];
TextView website[];
TextView category[];
try {
URL url = new URL(
"http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
/** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
Node node = nodeList.item(i);
name[i] = new TextView(this);
website[i] = new TextView(this);
category[i] = new TextView(this);
Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
name[i].setText("Name = "
+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("website");
Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
website[i].setText("Website = "
+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
category[i].setText("Website Category = "
+ websiteElement.getAttribute("category"));
layout.addView(name[i]);
layout.addView(website[i]);
layout.addView(category[i]);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}
/** Set the layout view to display */
setContentView(layout);
}
}
```

example.xml

```
<maintag>
<item>
<name>AndroidPeople</name>
<website category="android">www.androidpeople.com</website>
</item>
<item>
<name>iPhoneAppDeveloper</name>
<website category="iPhone">www.iphone-app-developer.com</website>
</item>
</maintag>
```

i m not able to get output for the above code.. got some exception in android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException and gralloc_goldfish error (i.e) Emulator without GPU emulation detected .... help me for this problem. i gng this program for 2 days.. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this on a background thread (maybe using an `AsyncTask`).

A `NetworkOnMainThreadException` means exactly this - you are running a network call on the main UI thread. This is to encourage us to not make calls that block UI interaction.

`url.openStream()` is what triggers this.

Comment: So. what can i do now, so u plz suggest wat code i have to write, since i m new to andriod, i am not able to get you, thank you once again

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads